# Displacement Node + Color Ramp Accuracy

Tags: color, shader-nodes, displacement, height-map

For practice, I'm making a basic planet heightmap using nodes with a procedurally generated noise texture, I'm using the top color ramp to color the heights and depths of the ocean, though they're not accurately forming to the displacement (lower color ramp used to control flat spots). I believe I may need to add the top color ramp (for color) after the lower color ramp (for flat spots) but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

How can I combine the two to make an accurate heightmap where all displaced spots are varying green to red and flats are varying blue to deep blue at their center? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Please see pic for node structure and result (The glossy BSDF is just a basic node in place of the principled BDSF, and please disregard the spare bump map at the bottom, I realized that it was unnecessary to achieve the desired effect.) [image]

Comment: zoom in on the ColorRamp, set the last blue swatch position to `0.5`, and the next, green swatch position to `0.501`, then in the bottom ColorRamp set the first swatch to `0.5`.